# Ubuntu 20.04, black square with number "1" showing on top-left corner when try to start "settings"

Tags: settings

When I try to start settings shows this black box on top-left corner. Also, from right button on settings on the launcher, on all windows I see it is loaded, but window does not appear.

[image]

Comment: I issued "ls /sys/class/drm" ... i get :

card0       card0-HDMI-A-1  card0-VGA-1  card1-VGA-2  renderD129  version
card0-DP-1  card0-LVDS-1    card1        renderD128   ttm

Comment: Please add new information to your Question above, not to comments. Comments are intended to help you improve your question; to make it answerable. Comments are not intended for conversation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature which allows you to identify which monitor you are modifying the configuration for when you open Display Settings. It corresponds with the miniature monitor layout diagram shown in the Settings application in your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. I had a second workplace, where the settings window was; it was no problem at all...